# Hadoop slave tasktracker error "retrying to connect"

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, slave

I have a simple setup on EC2
One Master
One Slave

When I do JPS, I see everything except the tasktracker process. When I execute start-all.sh/stop-all.sh, I see the tasktracker message start,logging,stopping etc. I am able to run my pig commands in Mapreduce mode as well on the slave. But I cant do:

1. Cannot access the http://ec2machineSlave.com:50060/tasktracker.jsp
2. JPS does not show tasktracker
3. On Slave get error Retrying to connect to server ec2machineMaster/ipaddress:54300. Already tried x time(s)

I can SSH between Master to Slave. Created a id_dsa key on master, copied the id_dsa.pub to slave and did all the permission thing.

Can anyone suggest what could be wrong or if I need to trying something else.